# Comparing two columns per row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data-frame that is structured in a way that reflects the flow of a conversation (i.e. where each row is a reference to what someone has said. See below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydata = [[1, ['hello', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you']],
      [2, ['i','am', 'well', 'how' 'are', 'you']],
      [1, ['nice', 'weather', 'is', 'it', 'not']],
      [2, ['indeed', 'it','is', 'nice', 'weather']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
df.columns=['speaker','turn']
```

I am comparing word use at each turn and the left-adjacent turn (i..e the preceding turn). Thus far I am using the following to calculate the intersection between these two points:

```
df['adjacent_turn'] = df.turn.shift(1)
df['intersection'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: np.intersect1d(x.turn, x.adjacent_turn), axis=1
)
```

What I would now like is to have another column with the words that are in the 'turn' column but **not** in the adjacent column. I have tried what seemed to me to be a workable option but it seems I'm going wrong somewhere.

```
df['turn_only'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [word for word in x.turn if word not in x.adjacent_turn], axis=1
)
```

**Edit:** What I should have mentioned before is that it is important that I preserve the order of the original turn. That is, if I am omitting the word 'happy' in a turn that says 'i am feeling happy today', I would need the non-intersection column to return 'i', 'am', 'feeling', 'today' rather than in random order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do a set difference over the two columns:

```
## fill na - set difference wont work with NA values
df['adjacent_turn'] = df['adjacent_turn'].fillna('')

df['turn_only'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['turn']).difference(x['adjacent_turn'])), 1)

print(df.iloc[:,-2:])

              intersection                      turn_only
0                       []  [hello, how, you, are, there]
1                    [you]          [howare, am, i, well]
2                       []   [weather, is, it, nice, not]
3  [is, it, nice, weather]                       [indeed]
```

Comment: I have found that you can use `lambda x: np.setdiff1d(x['turn'], x['adjacent_turn']).tolist()` as an input function for `apply`. Which way is more advisable in `pandas`?

Comment: Not an expert but I'd guess using a Numpy func would be quicker than converting a series to set, and then to list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the order, I can do it with list comprehensions, but it isn't vectorised (so potentially slower):

```
res = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    try:
        res += [[word for word in row[2] if word not in row[3]]]
    except TypeError:
        res += [[np.NaN]]

df['turn_only'] = res
```

Result:

```
    speaker     turn             adjacent_turn  intersection    turn_only
0   1   [hello, there, how, are, you]   [nan]   []  [nan]
1   2   [i, am, well, howare, you]  [you]   [you]   [i, am, well, howare]
2   1   [nice, weather, is, it, not]    []  []  [nice, weather, is, it, not]
3   2   [indeed, it, is, nice, weather]     [it, is, nice, weather]     [is, it, nice, weather]     [indeed]
```

Note that this works better for your first case as well (intersection): unlike in numpy set ops, order is preserved.